# check if value if empty with vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

i´m trying to check if one value is empty and show message. In my form i set input value a white space and save it. In my column table i have this:

```
{{ (item.claseExtraccion != null) ? item.claseExtraccion : 'Sin clase extracción' }}
     <v-btn v-if="item.claseExtraccion != null || item.claseExtraccion == ''"
        class="xmin-15 h-auto my-0 mx-0 boton-icono"
        text color="secondary"
        title="Ampliar información"
        @click="abrirDialog({
                  'nombre': item.claseExtraccion
                })"
         >
        <i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn v-else>
          Sin clase extracción
      </v-btn>
```

always i can show this icon  i trayed with `item.claseExtraccion == ''` with `item.claseExtraccion.lenght == 0` but always same result.

My data in my console.log its
[image]

i don´t know that i´m doing wrong. I need validate that this value it´s empty and not null

**update**

My problem it´s, that always show:

[image]

i need that if clase extracción it´s empty or null set text in column "Sin clase extracción".

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english and if a bad question for its simplicity

Comment: What's the problem here? Can you show us the result you have vs. what you want?

Comment: @Kapcash thaks for your response. i update my question with my result and result that i hope get it

Comment: I think you should do `v-if="item.claseExtraccion != null || item.claseExtraccion !== ''"`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim thanks for your response. i´m getting same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly just check if value exists for `item.claseExtraccion`

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      item: {
        claseExtraccion: ''
      }
    };
  },
})
app.use(vuetify).mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.4/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<div id="demo">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-btn v-if="item.claseExtraccion"
        class="xmin-15 h-auto my-0 mx-0 boton-icono"
        text color="secondary"
        title="Ampliar información"
        @click="abrirDialog({'nombre': item.claseExtraccion})"
         >
         {{ item.claseExtraccion }}
        <i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn v-else>
          Sin clase extracción
      </v-btn>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, and your response it´s that i need. thank you very much... I didn't know it was so simple